# remove the top avrg value fl_chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

here give the issues picture

[image]

i tried to remove this top value its show the avrg but i want to remove it ..
here is my code..

```dart
  BarChartData(
              maxY: maxValue + 20,
              minY: 0,
              barGroups: _chartGroups(monthlyBarData),
              // titlesData: FlTitlesData(bottomTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: _bottomTitles)),
              borderData: FlBorderData(
                show: false,
              ),
              gridData: const FlGridData(
                  show: true,
                  drawHorizontalLine: true,
                  drawVerticalLine: false),
              titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                  sideTitles: _bottomTitles,
                ),
                topTitles: AxisTitles(
                  sideTitles: SideTitles(
                    getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) => Container(),
                    showTitles: true,
                    reservedSize: 10,
                  ),
                ),
                rightTitles:
                    const AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
                leftTitles: const AxisTitles(
                  sideTitles: SideTitles(
                    showTitles: true,
                    reservedSize: 40, // Adjust the value as needed
                  ),
                ),
                show: true,
              ),
              barTouchData: BarTouchData(
                  handleBuiltInTouches: true,
                  touchTooltipData:
                      BarTouchTooltipData(tooltipBgColor: Colors.white))),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

set only max value in "maxY" parameter and do not add any additional value otherwise it's will show same issue.

```
BarChartData(
              maxY: 50 ,
              alignment: BarChartAlignment.spaceAround,
              // titlesData: FlTitlesData(bottomTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: _bottomTitles)),
              borderData: FlBorderData(
                show: false,
              ),
              gridData: const FlGridData(
                  show: true, drawHorizontalLine: true, drawVerticalLine: false),
              titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                    sideTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  reservedSize: 10,
                )),
                topTitles: AxisTitles(
                  sideTitles: SideTitles(
                    getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) => Container(),
                    showTitles: true,
                    reservedSize: 10,
                  ),
                ),
                rightTitles:
                    const AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
                leftTitles: const AxisTitles(
                  sideTitles: SideTitles(
                    showTitles: true,
                    reservedSize: 40, // Adjust the value as needed
                  ),
                ),
                show: true,
              ),
              barTouchData: BarTouchData(
                  handleBuiltInTouches: true,
                  touchTooltipData:
                      BarTouchTooltipData(tooltipBgColor: Colors.white)))
```

[image]